# Efficiently read/shift out-of-range datetimes using pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

so I have a dataset (a bunch of csv files) which contains (anonymized) datetimes in the following form:

> 3202-11-11 14:51:00 EST

The dates have been shifted by some random time for each entity. So differences in time for a given entity are still meaningful.

When trying to convert using e.g. 
`pd.to_datetime(['3202-11-11 14:51:00 EST'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S EST')`, this will result in 'OutOfBoundsDatetime' error.

For my use case it would be ideal to specify a number of years by which to shift all dates when reading the csv files, s.t. they are within the valid pandas datetime range.

Do you have an idea how this could be solved efficiently? I have to do this on ~40k entities/csv files, with 10 to 10k such dates per csv.  (my non-efficient idea: Go through python datetime which works for years till 9999, shift dates there and then convert to pandas datetime)

**EDIT**: I also asked this question in IRC #pydata and got this answer (thanks jboy):

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> offset = timedelta(days=10000)
>>> df
                  time
0  3001-01-01 01:00:01
1  3001-01-01 01:00:02
2  3001-01-01 01:00:05
3  3001-01-01 01:00:09

>>> df['time'].map(lambda t: t - offset)
0    2973-08-15 01:00:01
1    2973-08-15 01:00:02
2    2973-08-15 01:00:05
3    2973-08-15 01:00:09
Name: time, dtype: object
```

The only thing I have to do differently was:

```
 df['time'].map(lambda t: datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S EST')-offset)
```

Because my time column was still str and not datetime.datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to work on this at the string level, deducting some number of years (in the following, 1200):

```
s = '3202-11-11 14:51:00 EST'

>>> In [21]: pd.to_datetime(str(int(s[: 4]) - 1200) + s[4: ])
Out[21]: Timestamp('2002-11-11 14:51:00')
```

You can also vectorize this. Say you start with

```
dates = pd.Series([s, s])
```

Then you can use

```
>>> pd.to_datetime((dates.str[: 4].astype(int) - 1200).astype(str) + dates.str[4: ])
0   2002-11-11 14:51:00
1   2002-11-11 14:51:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Great idea. In my case the dates are something the user provides so the year isn't necessarily in the beginning, but the user also has to provide the strptime format string so I can easily deduce the position of the year. I'd assume that this solution is quicker than the solution I added in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The pandas datetime object uses a 64-bit integer to represent time, and since it has nanosecond resolution, the upper limitation stops at `2262-04-11`, referenced [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits).

I'm not sure if you plan on doing any sort of time manipulations on the time objects, but if you just want them represented in the dataframe, I don't see why not use the python datetime object to just represent them as-is without doing any time shifting:

**EXAMPLE**

```
from datetime import datetime
s = pd.Series(['3202-11-11 14:51:00 EST', '9999-12-31 12:21:00 EST'])
s = s.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:-4], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

**RETURNS**

```
0    3202-11-11 14:51:00
1    9999-12-31 12:21:00
dtype: object
```

Running a quick sniff type check on the first cell:

```
>>> type(s[0])
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: That's what I've done so far, but it's quite annoying, since pandas tries to convert python datetimes to it's internal datetime format. This doesn't happen when the python datetime is out-of-range for pandas, but otherwise it does. Since I can also encounter dates in the pandas range this is pretty annoying (mixed types). You can get around it, but IMO it's just a workaround. I think it's cleaner to simply use the pandas datetime and it should work for me (with shifting the dates). Plus: I write the data to HDF -> python datetime have to be pickled. Thanks!