OutOfBoundsDatetime error occurs when using pd.Grouper() to group DataFrame by 100-year intervals
I have a dataframe, df with 2 columns, 'years' and 'count'. The 'years' column contains datetime values, and the 'count' column contains integers.
     years    count
0 2000-09-06      1
1 2157-11-16      1

When trying to group it by years using pd.Grouper as below
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='100YS',key='years')])
the OutOfBoundsDatetime error is encountered.
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2300-01-01 00:00:00
I understand that with freq = '100YS', the years are tried to group as 2000,2100,2200 etc.
Is there any way to prevent this error by passing in a max date value or any other approach to obtain the same result
For freq = '50YS', the expected result is obtained when performing df['count'].sum()
years
2000-01-01    1
2050-01-01    0
2100-01-01    0
2150-01-01    1


pandas doesn't handle dates that far

Explaining things: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39450309/12846804

In pandas > 2.0, you should be able to lower the granularity of the datetime dtype for the resampling column.
Solution
df['years'] = df['years'].astype({'years': 'datetime64[s]'})

print(
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='100YS', key='years')]).sum()
)
#             count
# years
# 2000-01-01      1
# 2100-01-01      1
# 2200-01-01      2

Copy/paste example
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__) # 2.2.2

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'years': pd.to_datetime(['2000-09-06', '2157-11-16', '2257-11-16']),
    'count':                [1,            1,            2,          ],
})

print(df.dtypes)
# years    datetime64[ns]
# count             int64
# dtype: object

# defaults to a datetime64[ns] dtype, need to convert to encompass larger years.
df['years'] = df['years'].astype({'years': 'datetime64[s]'})
print(
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='100YS', key='years')]).sum()
)
#             count
# years
# 2000-01-01      1
# 2100-01-01      1
# 2200-01-01      2

